# Set default active tabs and tasks based on the returned values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If `Get2` returns`null`, it tries to set the default to `Get1` ->`selectedTabId: res.data [0] .id`, `selectedTodoId: res.data [0] .id`. If `Get2` returns an object with the properties, it wants to set the active tab and the task based on what will return``` Get2 `` selectedTabId: res.data.task_id ```, `selectedTodoId: res.data.task_id`. Currently, `selectedTabId: res.data[0].id`, `selectedTodoId: res.data[0].id` is always set for me. `Get2` returns me a specific task (id) that appears in the array with`Get1` Please, give me some tips.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-soyase

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectedTodoId: '',
      selectedTabId: null,
      items: [],
      selectIndex: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    /*Get1*/
    axios({
        url: 'https://app',
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          items: res.data,
          selectedTabId: res.data[0].id,   
          selectedTodoId: res.data[0].id   
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })   

  /*Get2*/
    axios({
        url: 'https://app/tasks',
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          checkRunning: res.data,
          checkRunningId: res.data.id,
          selectedTabId: res.data.id
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })     
}

   select = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedTodoId: id,
      selectedTabId: id
    })
  }

  isActive = (id) => {
    return this.state.selectedTabId === id;
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items
              .map((item, index) =>
                <Item
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                  select={this.select}
                  items = {this.state.items}
                  selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
                  isActive= {this.isActive(item.id)}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to chain these promises directly, so that you can make sure, that the default Get1 is set, before you try to set the Get2. Look at this code to see how you could Implement it.

```
componentDidMount() {

    /*Get1*/
    axios({
       url: 'https://app',
       method: "GET"
    })
   .then(res => {
       this.setState({
          items: res.data,
          selectedTabId: res.data[0].id,
          selectedTodoId: res.data[0].id
       });
    })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
    })
    .then(() => {
       /*Get2*/
       axios({
           url: 'https://app/tasks',
           method: "GET"
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res) {
                this.setState({
                checkRunning: res.data,
                checkRunningId: res.data.id,
                selectedTabId: res.data.id
             });
         }
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
          })
     });
}
```

Now you set the default id tab from Get1 and after that, you download Get2 and if Get2 returns a valid object (you could extend that if(res) to check if it is an actual object and a valid response), the downloaded Get2 id is set. Hope this helps.